# How do I assign different values for different first.id in SAS

Tags: sas

How do I assign different values for different first.id in SAS. I have a data set. The data set is huge and I am just showing the portion here. Appreciated.

```
id
11
11
11
11
22
22
22
22
33
33
```

What I need is this,

```
id val
11 5
11 0
11 0
11 0
22 8
22 0
22 0
22 0
33 9
33 0
```

Comment: Where do 5, 8, and 9 come from? What have you tried? How big is your dataset? Additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have one value per id in a separate data set, you can `MERGE`  `BY ID` and reset the `val` to `0` when desired.

Example:

```
data have;
input id @@; datalines;
11 11 11 11
22 22 22 22
33 33
;

data values;
input id val; datalines;
11 5
22 8
33 9
;

data want;
  merge have values;
  by id;
  if not first.id then val = 0;
run;
```